# Run Github Actions when pull requests have a specific label

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

After reading the documentation of the [Events that trigger workflows](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull-request-event-pull_request), I wonder if it's possible to run a workflow with a **given label name**, like RFR or WIP.

I know we can run a workflow when the pull request is labeled, but there is nothing more for a specifc label name :

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [labeled]
```

Has anyone done this before ?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can achieve **running a workflow on labeling a Pull Request** using a conditional expression like

```
if: ${{ github.event.label.name == 'label_name' }}
```

So if you have your GitHub action config as below

```
name: CI

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ labeled ]

jobs:
  build:
    if: ${{ github.event.label.name == 'bug' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Run a one-line script
      run: echo Hello, world!
```

It would trigger the workflow whenever a PR is labeled and **run the job only if the label is `bug`** and would **skip if the label is anything else**. You can also use `github.event.action == 'labeled'` as an extra check but that is not required if you have only `types: [ labeled ]` for the `pull_request` as shown in the config above.

**Note**: Just for your information, the github event has the following info (removed the irrelevant data for brevity) regarding the label in case of labelling a PR

```
"event": {
    "action": "labeled",
    "label": {
      "color": "d73a4a",
      "default": true,
      "description": "Something isn't working",
      "id": 1519136641,
      "name": "bug",
      "node_id": "abcd",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/labels/bug"
    }
}
```

**GitHub actions documentation** regarding conditional expressions is [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#about-contexts-and-expressions).

Comment: What is about multiple labels. For example if my PR hast two labels eg. `bug` and `security`. Does this approach will work?

Comment: @Markus this would trigger the workflow for every labelling event, so would work when you have multiple labels too.

Comment: Too bad, we can only run on labeling event. I wish it can continues run the action as long as the label is still assigned to the PR>

Comment: @Bozhao You can do this by checking the `github.event.pull_request.labels` field. Here's a simplified example: `if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, '<label_name>')`. You will also need to make sure you specify "labeled", "opened", "synchronize" and "reopened" in `pull_request.types`

Comment: @StephenYoung You should include that as an answer.

Comment: @StephenYoung how do you do it if you want to have a conditional where you don't want something to run if one or specific labels are present? For instance, I don't want to run a PR event workflow if 'maintenance' or 'WIP' are labels on the PR

Comment: Can we use similar label conditions on push? - From what I can see, labels are only available on the Pull Requests events, but wondered if anyone has found otherwise?

Comment: @Randy you can add a '!' before the expression:

 if: "!contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'hotfix')"

Answer (score 31):

Per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325286/run-github-actions-when-pull-requests-have-a-specific-label#comment122159108_62331521), the condition to check is:

```yaml
   if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, '<label_name>')
```

Comment: If you add this on a `pull_request` workflow, it doesn't pick up the labels added after the PR was raised. 
In that case, one needs to close and re-open the PR or just create a new PR.

Comment: It depends on your trigger. If you don't have a `PR labeled` trigger in your workflow then it wouldn't work. You need this: `on: pull_request: types: [ labeled ]` @vishwarajanand

Comment: @vishwarajanand I think you're only partially correct. If you push up another commit, Github will recognize the new labels.

Comment: You both seem correct, it seems due to the default pull_request activity type. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows suggests default activity type is opened, synchronize, or reopened and not labelled.

Answer (score 8):

I didn't need to have the `labeled` type to make it work, just as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74829754/3756686) I've manage to have it working with this condition:

```
name: ExampleWorkflow
on:  
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  ExampleJob:
    if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'example-label')
```

This way, the workflow `ExampleWorkflow` will be triggered for any pull request with target branch `main` and the job `ExampleJob` will be skipped if the PR doesn't have the label `example-label`