# Disable Github Action workflow, only run when desired

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have some very expensive benchmarks/tests which I'd only like to run on some PRs, not all. Is there a way to do this with github actions?

Comment: What is your criterion for running or not running the benchmarks and tests?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways.
Most of the workflow triggers can be further specified through "Activity Types".
For Pull Requests, they are:

> - assigned
> - unassigned
> - labeled
> - unlabeled
> - opened
> - edited
> - closed
> - reopened
> - synchronize
> - ready_for_review
> - locked
> - unlocked
> - review_requested
> - review_request_removed

[(Docs as Source)](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request)

Now, you could run the workflow only for PRs matching a certain [pattern](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags):

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'benchmark/**'
```

You could also do it with [labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325286/run-github-actions-when-pull-requests-have-a-specific-label):

```
on:
  pull_request: labeled
...
jobs:
  check-label:
    if: ${{ github.event.label.name == 'benchmark' }}
...
```

And of course you can also always use [manual triggers](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) only:

```
on: workflow_dispatch
```