# Getting name of labels in githubs action

Tags: github-actions

I m writing a GitHub workflow that will run the unit test cases. But if PR has a WIP label I need to skip it. Which expression I can use to get the array of names of labels of the pr.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325286/run-github-actions-when-pull-requests-have-a-specific-label

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Github Actions when pull requests have a specific label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325286/run-github-actions-when-pull-requests-have-a-specific-label)