# Trigger diferent jobs depending on pull request type

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to reduce the amount of files I have for my workflows from 4 to 1. And with that my `on` is like this:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, closed]
  push:
    branches: [master]
```

I know it's possible to use `if` in workflows but looking at the documentation I didn't find which parameters I should use to trigger the correct jobs when:

- Pull request is opened
- Pull request is closed
- Push is made to a existing pull request
- Push is made to a brach

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325286/run-github-actions-when-pull-requests-have-a-specific-label/62331521#62331521) of mine for something similar, where I have provided a sample event payload too. Essentially you need to use `github.event.action` in the `if` condition. For eg `if: ${{ github.event.action == 'opened' }}`

Comment: You can enable a webhook on GitHub for different events and check what's the value that comes under `github.event` for each event and based on that have conditions for whichever events you need.

Answer (score -1):

The piece of documentation that touches on how to use **if** is [this one](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions).

You can use it at the job level. Consider the following example to execute a job only when the PR has been closed and merged (not just closed):

```
name: Build Your App

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ closed ]
    
jobs:
  build:
    # this job will only run if the PR has been merged, not just 'closed'
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: '0'
```

And you can also use it at the step level, to execute or not the step based on the `{{ expression }}` evaluation, as the documentation shows.

Based on your ask, I would use the information on the `github.event.*` payload. To do that I use to re-create the conditions and triggers on a test repository and print it to the console. Then I know what I have to look for in each kind of event. It's like debugging the events. [This](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log) is the documentation to do that.