# Is pull_request.label available to a Github Action?

Tags: github-actions, pull-request

I am trying to start a workflow only if the merged `pull_request` has a specific label.

The `merged` key is referenced [here](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request) within an `action`. The Pull object itself is documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls). But I don't see `merged` documented by itself or with other keys.

Is `pull_request.label` available to a Github Action? Is there a comprehensive doc that shows all the keys available to a `pull_request`?

Comment: According to the link you shared, you could get the first label name in your workflow triggered by a pull_request event using `github.event.pull_request.labels.[0].name` (and use a script to get all the other values in a variable if you need to). I believe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325286/run-github-actions-when-pull-requests-have-a-specific-label) could be useful as well, for example using `if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, '<label_name>')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To list all labels you can use something like this

```
       x=${{ toJson(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name) }}
       echo $x
```

Also to use a single label you can try

```
steps:
      - name: deploy        
        if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'deploy')      
        run: |
          echo "deploy"
```

Comment: Thank you, @pavan! I had some issues with marshaling using your first statement, though I think it had more to do with local tests using https://github.com/nektos/act. Your second statement above did the trick!

Comment: The second statement didn't work because `github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name` returns an array and `contains()` is comparing strings. 
This will work `contains(toJson(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name), 'deploy')`.

Comment: Actually the second should work. [According to the docs example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example-using-an-object-filter) this is exactly how you can check the labels.